# Poisson distribution with changing interval

Tags: probability, factorial, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to learn how to use Poisson distribution for questions involving changing intervals. I have the following exercise:

Ron gets on average 5 points a day (24 hours) in his computer game. What is the probability for getting zero points during a) one day b) one afternoon (8 hours)?

So for a I have the following formula: $\frac{5^0e^{-5}}{0!}$

However when I try to adjust it to include only one third (8/24 hours), I encounter the situation where I should take a factorial of $\frac{5}{3}$, which is not integer. Do you have any tips how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the reproducibility property of poisson distribution, the number of point get in 8 hours follows a $Po\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X=0]=\frac{e^{-5/3}\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^0}{0!}=e^{-5/3}$$